# How to subset rows that contains the same string twice

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame which looks as follows.

```
> dput(head(wp_data_ensembl))

structure(list(wpid = c("WP3633", "WP3633", "WP3633", "WP694", 
"WP694", "WP694"), gene = c("ENSG00000156006", "ENSG00000156006", 
"ENSG00000156006", "ENSG00000156006", "ENSG00000156006", "ENSG00000156006"
), wpid = c("WP702", "WP694", "WP3633", "WP702", "WP694", "WP3633"
), name = c("Metapathway biotransformation Phase I and II", "Arylamine metabolism", 
"Caffeine and Theobromine metabolism", "Metapathway biotransformation Phase I and II", 
"Arylamine metabolism", "Caffeine and Theobromine metabolism"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The data frame contains two columns both names wpid. I would like to subset all rows where both columns have the same string.

For example out of the following rows.

```
   wpid            gene   wpid                                         name
1 WP3633 ENSG00000156006  WP702 Metapathway biotransformation Phase I and II
2 WP3633 ENSG00000156006  WP694                         Arylamine metabolism
3 WP3633 ENSG00000156006 WP3633          Caffeine and Theobromine metabolism
```

Only the 3rd row should remain in the new data frame.

Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: It is not advisable to have samee column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do vector comparisons. In R, this is implicit. Try this your self:

```
wp_data_ensembl[,1] == wp_data_ensembl[,3]
[1] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

You can then do subsetting with a logical vector (the returned object from the above row:

```
wp_data_ensembl[wp_data_ensembl[,1] == wp_data_ensembl[,3], ]
```

Answer (score 2):

As the column names are same (not recommended though), we can do a `group_by_at` with index and then `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by_at(1:3) %>% 
  slice(n())
```

---

If we need to `filter` all the instances where both columns are same, change the column names to `unique` as duplicate names wouldn't work in the pipe and would create only confusion, then do a `filter`

```
df1 %>%
    set_names(make.unique(names(.))) %>% 
    filter(wpid == wpid.1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This code subset the data from 336623 rows to 25122 rows. But there were multiple mismatches between columns 1 and 3. I can't quite tell what it did.

Comment: sorry will be more precise. There are still many rows that contain characters in columns 1 and 3 which do not match after using the dplyr code.